# Is it okay to initialise WeakReference with a null value?

Tags: c#, weak-references

I have a class which will only ever have a single instance at a time. It's essentially a singleton that is destroyed when no external references are held and re-instantiated when you need a new reference later.

```
private static readonly WeakReference<Foo> weakInstance = new WeakReference<Foo>(null);
```

The reason for the above code is because I have native iOS callbacks (which must be static functions) but which need to pass data to the current instance.

**tl;dr** Is it safe to initialise a `WeakReference` to null and set the target later? Is this a code smell?

**Edit:**
As @smolchanovsky pointed out, I could just instantiate the weak reference when I need to set it. This results in:

```
if (weakInstance == null)
{
    weakInstance = new WeakReference<Foo>(this);
}
else
{
    weakInstance.SetTarget(this);
}
```

or

```
// Overwrite the existing WeakReference object
weakInstance = new WeakReference<Foo>(this);
```

Is there a reason to pick one of these over the other?

Comment: Why does the singleton need to be "destroyed" when not in use? Because bear in mind, the weak referenced object will only be collected if a collection occurs after the last strong reference goes away. So it *may* still be there after a long period of non use. Based on that, which way do you need to go? If it needs "destroying", weak reference doesn't do that. If you can tolerate it sticking around, why not forgo the complexity and just have a `Lazy` that in fact never does get cleared down until the process exits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use this?

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static WeakReference<Singleton> weakInstance;

    public WeakReference<Singleton> Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (weakInstance == null)
                weakInstance = new WeakReference<Singleton>(this);
            else
                weakInstance.SetTarget(this);
            return weakInstance;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this isn't a thread safe solution.

Comment: Because then I'll have to check for null before setting it, which adds clutter for a use case that only happens once.

Comment: I still don't see the problem.